# Method to check header token if valid

Tags: security, go

I've written the following function which reads an authorization header, compares it and returns whether it is valid or not.

The function works correctly:

```
func Auth(req *http.Request) bool{
    sHeader := strings.SplitN(req.Header.Get("authorization"), " ", 2)
    if sHeader[0] != "" {
        fmt.Printf("sHeader: ", sHeader[1])
        devEnv := os.Getenv("authorization")
        if (devEnv == sHeader[1]) {
            fmt.Println("valid")
            return true
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Not valid: " + sHeader[1])
            return false
        }
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Missing Authorization Header")
        return false
    }
}
```

What can I improve?

Comment: "(I see lot of view's but no comments ;-) )" Nina watcher. Really! You only posted this about two hours ago. We are unpaid volunteers.

Comment: @peterSO - sorry I just suspect that my code is perferct which is obviously  not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my notes that I would bring to the code review.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func AuthCodeReview(req *http.Request) bool { // why bool? why not error
    sHeader := strings.SplitN(req.Header.Get("authorization"), " ", 3) // 3 for fields after 0 & 1?
    if len(sHeader) == 0 || sHeader[0] == "" {                         // check index in range
        log.Print("Missing Authorization Header") // never Fatal!
        return false
    }
    if len(sHeader) > 1 { // why 1? why ignore 0? check index in range
        fmt.Printf("sHeader: ", sHeader[1])  // debug?
        devEnv := os.Getenv("authorization") // LookupEnv?
        if devEnv == sHeader[1] {
            fmt.Println("valid") // debug?
            return true
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Not valid: " + sHeader[1]) // debug?
    return false
}

func Auth(req *http.Request) bool {
    sHeader := strings.SplitN(req.Header.Get("authorization"), " ", 2)
    if sHeader[0] != "" {
        fmt.Printf("sHeader: ", sHeader[1])
        devEnv := os.Getenv("authorization")
        if devEnv == sHeader[1] {
            fmt.Println("valid")
            return true
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Not valid: " + sHeader[1])
            return false
        }
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Missing Authorization Header")
        return false
    }
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_MwBV80vWx

---

---

> `log.Fatal` is equivalent to `log.Print()` followed by a call to
>   `os.Exit(1)`.
>
> `os.Exit` causes the current program to exit with the given status code.
>   The program terminates immediately; deferred functions are not run.

Your program is running 100,000 client connections using goroutines. One connection has a problem, so you crash the program. We have 100,000 very upset customers. Handle errors and fail gracefully; return errors; don't `panic` or `Exit`.

See [Errors](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors).

---

```
fmt.Println("valid") // debug?
```

Your `sysout` is a massive clutter of messages. That may make sense for debugging, but it doesn't make sense for production. What is the purpose of this and similar statements.

---

```
fmt.Println("Not valid: " + sHeader[1]) // debug?
```

If this message is not for debugging, it should be logged (`log` not `fmt`).

---

> `strings.SplitN` The count determines the number of substrings to
>   return: n > 0: at most n substrings; the last substring will be the
>   unsplit remainder.

```
// 3 for fields after 0 & 1?
sHeader := strings.SplitN(req.Header.Get("authorization"), " ", 3)
```

If you are expecting two fields `SplitN`(2) will return the first field in index `0` and any remainder in index `1`. `SplitN`(3) will return the first field in index `0`, the second field in index `1` and any remainder in index `2`. Having a remainder may or may not be valid.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/IQA8iqIdN5

---

```
sHeader[1] // why 1? why ignore 0?
```

You don't say what the format of `req.Header.Get("authorization")` is. What does `sHeader[1]` represent. Add a comment to define `sHeader` and `sHeader[1]`.

---

I reorganized your code.

Don't write code as a heavily indented stream of consciousness. First, write the normal flow. The first step in a code review is to read and verify the normal flow, it should be obvious. Second, add exception handling. Third, add error handling. Sensibly minimize indentation.

See [Indent Error Flow](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#indent-error-flow).

For example, a simple first draft,

```
func AuthFirstDraft(req *http.Request) error {
    // TODO: improve error detection and handling
    sHeader := strings.SplitN(req.Header.Get("authorization"), " ", 3)
    devEnv := os.Getenv("authorization")
    if len(sHeader) > 1 && devEnv == sHeader[1] {
        return nil
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("error")
}
```

---

Code review is an iterative process. If there are significant changes, open a **new** question with the revised code.

Comment: Thanks a lot 1+ 

few clarification which I need in order to understand :) 

1 . you write `never fatal!` why? 
2. you write `debug ?` how should I change it to be printed only on debug, this is just trace… ?
3. you change the number `req.Header …. 3) ` to 3 which is working, why it works with 2 either ? 
4. I use bool that the caller can split with simple if to get the value , you suggest error , how should I adopt it to error if it’s better ?

Thanks a lot, this is what I want in order to learn!!!!

Comment: i've close the question but it will be great if you can still answer my questions , I want to learn from you. thanks!

Comment: @Ninawatcher: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , just last question, if I use the `AuthFirstDraft` should I use try catch block ?or can you provide example of the two caller when it success and if not how its recommended to catch the error ? thank a lot for this explanation!!!!